# How do I create a unique instance of an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, deep-copy

I've been working on my own javascript library, kis-js. I recently converted it to work with dom selectors like jQuery, but because of javascript copying only references I have this issue:

If you call `$_` twice, the second time you call it changes the result of the first call.

Test Code:

```
<h1>Heading</h1>
<a>Anchor</a>
<script>
  var anchor = $_("a");
  var heading = $_("h1");
  console.log(anchor.el); // should be <a>, but it's <h1>
</script>
```

Here's the source to the library: https://github.com/timw4mail/kis-js/blob/master/kis.js

I was thinking I needed to create a deep-copy of the constructor object, but I'm not quite sure how to go about that.

Edit:

I created a deep copy function:

```
dcopy = function(obj)
{
    var type, f;

    if(obj == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    if(typeof Object.create !== "undefined")
    {
        return Object.create(obj);
    }

    var type = typeof obj;

    if(type !== "object" && type !== "function")
    {
        return;
    }

    var f = function(){};

    f.prototype = obj;

    return new f();

};
```

How can I use this so that I can extend my constructed object?

Comment: [`jQuery.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend) can shallow / deep copy JavaScript objects.

Comment: @Paolo Moretti The whole point of the library is to not use jQuery.

Comment: @timw4mail I know, but you can look at the source code and see how it is implemented. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js

Comment: @Paolo Moretti @Danial A. White I updated the question. I've found "Javascript: The Definitive Guide" to be an excellent resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I just used this function.

```
dcopy = function(obj) {
var type, f;

if(obj == null)
{
    return;
}

if(typeof Object.create !== "undefined")
{
    return Object.create(obj);
}

var type = typeof obj;

if(type !== "object" && type !== "function")
{
    return;
}

var f = function(){};

f.prototype = obj;

return new f();

};
```

Answer (score 2):

You should return something `new`... Also, avoid assigning and returning global variables.

Comment: Okay, but where? The selector function? The constructor function? both?

Comment: If I don't assign a global variable, I won't have a way to use the library. That's the only global variable assigned.